# How to do assign awk output to variables

Tags: bash, awk

I would like to search through file.txt find all lines with foo in it then filter out column 3(aaa colum) then assign each instance of aaa to a different variable.
I got as far as filter out all instance of aaa, but it was just a print out. any ideas.  Im guessing it has to be a loop of some sort. my example is below.

```
grep foo file.txt | awk '{print $3}'
```

file.txt

```
1. foo  bar1    aaa1    bbb1    ccc1

2. blablabla...

3. foo  bar2    aaa2    bbb2    ccc2

4. blablabla...

5. foo  bar3    aaa3    bbb3    ccc3

6. blablabla...
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with the assigned instances?

Comment: Search other files for them using grep.

Comment: Then say that in your question.  To get yourself out of "user" status into "developer" status, you have to not think how you're going to solve the problem before you've actually stated it clearly.  25 years  in development, that was a constant problem: users demand we implement a particular solution because they imagine it will solve their problem.  They're human just like us: the first solution they think of is pretty much guaranteed wrong.

Comment: So I dont think I was very clear. aaa is not always going to be aaa it is a time stamp, but that time stamp will always be associated with foo

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a basic tutorial in `awk` -- a google search 'awk tutorial' will get you a few.

```
awk '$1=="foo"{$3="someothervalue";}{print;}' file.text
```

should do what you ask assuming "foo" is always in column  1 and aaa is always in coulmn 3 -- there is no need for grep.  There are two blocks, the first updates the aaa value to something else for the record marked "foo", and the second block prints all record, including the modification if any.

**Update**: or if all you want is to get the value of "aaa" for the records where "foo" is the key; you simply do this

```
awk '$1=="foo"{print $3;}' file.text
```

This will simply find all records which is marked "foo" and print the 3rd column (the "aaa")

Comment: So I dont think I was very clear. aaa is not always going to be aaa it is a time stamp, but that time stamp will always be associated with foo.

Comment: got it -- Added another example to address this.

Comment: I got your last code to work but instead of listing out the timestamps I want to assigned each time stamp to a separate variable.

Comment: ... and then do what with the variables?  You could create an array of the `aaa` (aka timestamps) variables, but this looks more like 101 basic awk reading manual stuff -- you should probably just read a awk-tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's comment, there is not really a need to store the matches. You can just do this to use the output of `awk` as input to grep through other files.

```
 awk '$3 ~ /aaa/ {print $3}' file.txt  | xargs -I {} grep {}  <OTHER_FILES_HERE>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to search through file.txt find all lines with foo

```
awk '/foo/
```

> then filter out column 3

```
awk '/foo/ {print $3
```

> then assign each instance of aaa to a different variable.

> `aaa=($(awk '/foo/{print $3}'`*`files`*)
>   `echo ${aaa[0])`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you meant that you wanted to store the values in shell environment variables.
If you really do want to store the values in variables you could use eval to assign the variables:

```
eval $(grep foo file.txt | awk '{count+=1; print "AAA"count"="$3";"}')
```

This makes a separate variable for each value it finds.

Answer (score 0):

merlin2011's suggestion to use xargs is good, but you can also use a simple shell loop and reuse the same variable name:

```
awk '/foo/{print $3}' |
while read value; do
  grep "$value" file
done
```

This assigns the output of awk to the variable "value" and executes the body of the loop once for each line generated by awk.